# Would a question about brain activity during different video games be on topic?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

I am interested to learn about any statistics on levels of brain activity during video games, specifically to learn about differences in games' effects on people's problem solving ability. (I am interested to know if certain games improve problem solving, and if other games do not, or even if other games even worsen someone's problem solving ability).

My interest comes from [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sXdfRYyzbmU) discussion where it's said:

> Generally, you want education to be as close to ... a good video game as possible.

Would such a question be on topic here, or best asked elsewhere?

Comment: BTW, we have a sister site [psychology.se].

Answer (score 8):

I would expect this type of question to be generally off topic *unless* the brain activity itself is involved in the gameplay. Games that [directly involve brain activity](https://www.technologyreview.com/2017/08/09/68005/mind-controlled-vr-game-really-works) do exist. Although they will probably become available to the general public at some point in the near future, that doesn't sound like what you're asking about.

To me, it sounds like your question is more about [the effects of different games on the person playing it](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6826942/). That is probably more appropriate on an educational/psychological Stack Exchange site where you will be more likely to find experts that can answer the question.

Answer (score 3):

I would say *maybe* not.

The help center states that these are allowed:

- Gameplay strategies and tactics
- Puzzle solving or obstacle clearing
- Game mechanics and terminology
- Plot and characters in games
- Game-specific hardware and utilities

The second one *might* mean this is allowed, but I'm not sure, as it seems more intended to be about the process of solving a specific puzzle. However, its not explicitly stated to be *not* allowed. I would go ahead and ask it, and just see how it goes, although it might be beneficial to do some of your own research trying to find studies about it first.